# Lookup a value if the dates fall between two dates

Tags: excel, date, lookup, between

I have window dates in two cells. For example:

- a1 = 1/1/2014 8:00
- b1 = 1/4/2014 10:00
- c1 = 11

Where

- A is the start date
- B is the end date
- C is the code for the window

In cell d1 I have the date: 1/3/2014 7:00

I would like to look up the date in a/b and if d falls between those dates then I would like for it to return the code for the window.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: 1) is it possible that `D1` would fall into two or more windows? 2) column C always contains numbers?

Comment: is this vba/excel forumlas you want?

Comment: what do you return if it is outside the dates?

Comment: I would like an excel code please.

Comment: D1 would not fall into more than 1 windows and C always contains numbers

Comment: it could just say "false" or "outside"

Comment: what if it doesn't fall into any?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have multiple "windows" listed in order with no gaps perhaps try LOOKUP like

`=LOOKUP(D1,A1:C10)`

see [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h1l1pgr0dvv3xp/codes.xls)

Comment: this doesn't check if it is in range?

Comment: Assuming no gaps between ranges and ranges in ascending order you don't really need to check within ranges - the Lookup matches D1 with the relevant column A value and returns the correct number from column C. If D1 may not be in any range then you can add a simple IF, like `=IF(D1>B10,NA(),LOOKUP(D1,A1:C10))`

Answer (score 2):

```
Cell 

a1      = 1/1/2014 8:00

b1      = 1/4/2014 10:00

c1      = 11

d1      = 1/3/2014 7:00

e1      =IF(AND($D$1-A1>0,B1-$D$1>0),C1,"outside")
```

[image: add add other rows filling down with cells a1:c52]

Comment: I have 52 windows...so I would have to do 52 if statements that are nested

Comment: That's why LOOKUP is good - you can check all 52 windows in one go - see my answer

Comment: your lookup doesn't check if it is between two dates.

Comment: Your question could be clearer. Do you just want to look up which windows, across multiple rows that don't exist in your question eg. a1:c52 ? each row being a different window?

Comment: if you want to do a lookup do one to find the first row where $Cn==$En.

Comment: 52 windows? Are they weeks?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this, it will work even if the dates are not in order, as long as values in C column are numeric. It will return 0 if no match

```
=SUMPRODUCT((D1>=A1:A10)*(D1<=B1:B10)*C1:C10)
```

Comment: I was waiting for somebody to suggest SUMPRODUCT or SUMIFS, +1 - personally I always prefer to use "lookup" type formulas when a single value is required - they can also be used for retrieving text values...but this approach has advantages, e.g. can have gaps, don't need to be sorted as you say

Comment: Yeh, eventually, if column C is not numeric we add a match to look for value 1 and then use index to get the value. But, in that case, it will be an array formula...